# How to generate subsets with the highest T-value

Tags: data-mining, data-preprocessing

I following [this](http://www.kdnuggets.com/data_mining_course/assignments/final-project.html)  data mining project. It explains how to do it but I don't understand the T-value part.

**"For each class, generate subsets with top 2,4,6,8,10,12,15,20,25, and 30 top genes with the highest T-value"**

So I calculate the T-value like this:

$$(Avg1 - Avg2) / \sqrt(Stdev1^2/N1+ Stdev2^2/N2)$$

- $Avg1$ is the average for one class across the gene sample and $Avg2$ is
  the average for the other 4 classes.
- $Stdev1$ is the standard deviation for one class and $Stdev2$ is the
  standard deviation for the other classes.
- $N1$ is the number of samples that have the class whose $T-value$ we are
  interested in, and $N2$ is the number of samples that does not have the
  $T-value$ that we are interested in.

---

How do I use that T-value to create those subsets?

[image: The Data]
The bold values in the data represent Average and Stdev per column.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "get rid of"?

Comment: remove the column

Comment: But what does that *mean* for your analysis?  Are you asking about how to write a macro to remove columns based on values in certain cells in Excel?  If not, what is the intended interpretation of removing a column (and why should it depend on a t test, which was never intended for such purposes)?

Comment: I'm not asking about Excel. I am trying to remove columns that won't help classify the data when training. What is T-value used for then? On that webpage the tutorial says to generate subsets with top 2, 4, 6, 8...30 columns with highest T-value. Does anyone understand that?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably simpler than you think. You need to sort the genes by their (absolute) T-values and keep the first 2, then keep the first 4, ..., then keep the first 30.

The logic behind is to identify the “most differentially regulated” genes, with the assumption that when the T-value is large (in absolute value), the corresponding gene will have a high expression in one condition, and a low expression in the other. A subset of genes that have this property are typically used as a “signature” for these conditions (for instance cancer versus non cancer, which can be later used for diagnosis).